# Arduino - get hour from char array Date header into string or float

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am building a real time clock with arduino and esp8266-01. With AT commands i am sending to google a request and the response from google i am putting in a char array. At the end i am getting

buffer[] = 'Date: 12 feb, 2016, 10:22:44 GMT';

Now i need to get the hour, minute and seconds from this buffer to be able to use setTime(hour,minutes,seconds,day,mount,year) from time library. Can anyone please help me with a piece of code to show me how to do this? I don't really know how to work with char arrays. I've tried to concatenate buffer[x] with buffer[x+1] to get hour and so on and put them in a string then to make a float but i can't manage. Thanks alot!

Comment: For example [RTCLib](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib) supports setting the time from similar strings (date and time separately). So you can get some inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `sscanf` function.

Example:

```
buffer[] = 'Date: 12 feb, 2016, 10:22:44 GMT';
int y,d,h,m,s;
char month[10];
sscanf(buffer,"Date: %i %s, %i, %i:%i:%i", &d, month, &y, &h, &m, &s);
```